# PayPal sandbox which credit card to use?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the sandbox [**url**](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=someone@email.com&item_name=Test%20Test123%20Order:01/06/2015&currency_code=GBP&amount=99.00&button_subtype=services&return=http://test.com/ID/44213b6e-b002-e511-80fa-c4346badf014) for accepting test payment through paypal.

When a user clicks a button he is redirected to paypal sandbox site. On the paypal sandbox site the user is presented with an option to pay using credit card. However when I try test credit card 4111-1111-1111-1111 it gives me the following error "The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different debit or credit card number."

I am not sure what am I missing?

Comment: try from here : http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/

Comment: I just tried that it says "You have entered an invalid number or incomplete debit or credit card number. Please check your entry and try again".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is documented](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#credit-card-numbers-for-testing)

Comment: Thanks EdSF for your reply. Did you read the question properly? I have already mentioned that I am using 4111-1111-1111-1111 which is a Visa test credit card number and is also present in the link you have shared. The issue is the test credit card that PayPal recommend are not working. I am not sure if there is a setting I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

The numbers provided in the documentation are used so much that the sandbox servers just don't accept them anymore.  They really need to update the docs.

I would recommend generating fresh credit card numbers to use.  I always [use this site](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/) for that.  The numbers it generates will work fine in the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks! I was breaking my head against the wall trying all those numbers on Paypal's doc site. They really should update those docs.

Comment: This option no longer appears to work either. I am getting "The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different debit or credit card number." when using one of the randomly-generated credit card numbers on the linked web page.

Comment: I use card numbers generated from that site successfully every day, so I know it still works.  Did you give up right when that happened or did you try another number?  Are you getting that error with every number you try from that site?